# Excel VBA Prevent Save with Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working with VBA in a template spreadsheet to prevent users from saving without certain fields being populated.  As the time has gone by, I've been requested to make a few stipulations on the entries being required based on the contents of other cells.  I have a bunch of data validation with drop-downs in my spreadsheet, so I'm too concerned about the targeting specific phrases to bypass requiring an entry to save the document. I need to keep all of the existing mandatory fields, but add in the exemptions below.

I currently have column M as a required columns if another of the other specified columns in that row are filled.  Per above, trying to make column M required for all scenarios except the following.  In the attempt to simplify the criteria, I've substituted the actual text required in both scenarios:

- Column M is not required if column G = "Alpha" and column J =
  "Bravo".
- Column M is not required if if the last four characters in
  column H are "abcd".

My current code is below.  This is revised from when the question was initially asked

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Const CHECK_RNG As String = "A1:D1,F1:K1,N1:N1,S1:Y1,AE1"
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range, c As Range
    Dim bCanSave As Boolean, sep As String
    Dim sWarning As String, sMissing As String, r As Long, ct As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Main")

    sWarning = "File not saved!" & vbNewLine & "Mandatory cells missing in rows: " & vbNewLine
    bCanSave = True


    For r = 2 To 1000
        Set rg = ws.Rows(r).Range(CHECK_RNG)
        ct = Application.CountA(rg)
        If ct > 0 And ct <> rg.Cells.Count Then
            bCanSave = False
            sMissing = sMissing & sep & r
            sep = ","
        End If
    Next r

    If Not bCanSave Then
        MsgBox sWarning & sMissing, vbExclamation
        Cancel = True
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Good that you've got code - what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @SJR, right now if there is data in columns A-D, F-K, S-Y, or AE in any given row, column M is required in that row for the spreadsheet to be saved.  Per what I have in question, I'm trying to make stipulations in those other columns so that column M can be left blank and still allow the spreadsheet to save.

Comment: Yes I see that, but what exactly is the difficulty you are having in implementing this? Have you tried code which hasn't worked? If so, please post it.

Comment: I would check column M first and if there is a value then move to the next row, if not then do your validation checks.  No reason to check all the others if Column M has valid required data.  I do not see in your posted code, as noted by @SJR, any check for values.

Comment: @SJR: I don't have any new code for what I'm trying to achieve.  I know little of VBA, and am really just an effective Googler.  I've been able to find some thoughts on it, but nothing that's I've been able to get to work, even independent of the existing code.  

Another user on Stack Overflow helped clean up the code above, from something I had pieced together from a few different websites, but inserting these new stipulations is over my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you're after as your current code doesn't appear to me to do what you say it does so I may have misunderstood.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim bCanSave As Boolean, sep As String
Dim sWarning As String, sMissing As String, r As Long, ct As Long
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, b As Boolean

Set ws = Sheets("Main")
Set wf = WorksheetFunction

sWarning = "File not saved!" & vbNewLine & "Mandatory cells missing in rows: " & vbNewLine
bCanSave = True
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Interior.Color = xlNone
For r = 2 To 10
    Set r1 = Union(Cells(r, "A").Resize(, 4), Cells(r, "F").Resize(, 6), Cells(r, "M"), Cells(r, "S").Resize(, 7), Cells(r, "AE"))
    If If wf.CountA(r1) = r1.Count - 1 And (Cells(r, "M") = vbNullString And _
            (Cells(r, "G") = "Alpha" And Cells(r, "J") = "Bravo") Or Right(Cells(r, "H"), 4) = "abcd") Then
                'no problem
    Else
        If wf.CountA(r1) > 0 And wf.CountA(r1) < r1.Count Then
            For Each r2 In r1.Areas
                If wf.CountBlank(r2) > 0 Then
                    If r2.Count > 1 Then
                        r2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    Else
                        r2.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    End If
                    b = True
                End If
            Next r2
        End If
        If b Then
            bCanSave = False
            sMissing = sMissing & sep & r
            sep = ","
            b = False
        End If
    End If
Next r

If Not bCanSave Then
    MsgBox sWarning & sMissing, vbExclamation
    Cancel = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry...while testing it, I realized what I had in my original post had a failed attempt at using VBA to affect the cell fill color, that I eventually gave up on.  I fixed it in the question above.  

I attempted to test what you had posted; it's allowing column M to be blank, regardless of the other specified columns.  I still need to prevent a save if those new criteria aren't present.  I think I've figured it out by adding " Cells(r, "M").Resize(, 1)," in with the other r1 Range.  But, it's also requiring all of those rows to be filled, totally blank rows should not prevent a save.

Comment: I think you need to spell out in more detail the precise requirements for when the file should or should not be saved.

Comment: Ok.  I have 20 required columns in a much larger spreadsheet (A-D, F-K, M, S-Y, AE).  If there is a row (beginning with row 2) with data in any of those columns, all of them should be required to save the document.  If all of those columns were blank in row in the range, the document could still be saved.  The coding in the question achieves this.  I'm trying to get it to maintain that ability, and add in an exception if either of the two criteria bulleted in the question are met.

Comment: Ah so there is nothing special about column M. I will revisit the code as I think I now follow what you want.

Comment: I've amended the code above so please let me know how you get on.

Comment: It is no longer requiring input for totally blank rows, so that's definitely progress.  However, it's not conditionally requiring the input in column M; it's letting it be blank no matter what the contents of the other specified cells in that row.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you so much!